# PHP: Request 50MB-100MB json - browser crash / do not display any result

Tags: javascript, php, json, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Huge json server requests: around 50MB - 100MB for example.

From what I know, it might crash when loading huge requests of data to a table (I usually use datatables), the result: memory reaches to almost 8G, and the browser crash. Chrome might not return a result, Firefox will usually ask if I want to wait or kill the process.

I'm going to start working on a project which will send requests for huge jsons, all compressed (done by the server side PHP). The purpose of my report is to fetch data, and display all in a table - made easy to filter and order. So I cant find the use of "lazy load"ing for this specific case.

I might use a vue-js datatable library this time (not sure which specifically).

- What's exactly using so much of my memory? I know for sure that the json result is received. Is that rendering/parsing of the json to the DOM? (I'm referring to the datatable example for now: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax)
- What is the best practices in these kind of situations? 
  I started researching this issue and noticed that there are posts from 2010 that seem like they're not relevant at all.

Comment: '*What's exactly using so much of my memory?*' - We can't say for sure without seeing some code, however, look out for potential memory leaks (recursive functions, queries etc.). '*What is the best practices in these kind of situations?*' - You could try a break the files up?

Comment: a datatable table insert from a json file as mentioned. example:https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit on the size of an HTTP response. There is a limit on other things, such as:

- local storage
- session storage
- cache
- cookies
- query string length
- memory (per your CPU limitations or browser allocation)

Instead, the problem is with your implementation of your datatable most likely. You can't just insert 100,000 nodes into the DOM and not expect some type of performance impact. Furthermore, if the datatable is performing logic against each of those datum as they're coming in and processing them before the node insertion, that's also going to be a big no no.

What you've done here is essentially pass the leg work of performing pagination from the server to the client, and with dire impacts.

If you must return a response that big, consider using one of the storage options that browsers provide (a few mentioned above). Then paginate off of the stored JSON response.

Comment: Store json variables in a local storage/session/cache/cookies? Is that even possible? Can you please add more details? I didn't know this is even possible.

Comment: @RickSanchez Sure. `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`, then `localStorage.getItem('key')` will produce `value`.

Comment: I have started researching this subject, I first went to read about caching the object variable (using `localStorage`). I figured that I cannot cache an object that is more than 2MB (I use 50MB-100MB). I got no permission saving data to the local machine in a somehow permanent way or with cookies, so cookies isn't an option. and saving to memory is the problem i'm trying to avoid (browser crashes). Which is most recommended to check our? session storage?

Comment: @RickSanchez To be quite frank, if your main goal here is to insert all of these rows into a table and do so with pagination on the client side, then my recommendation is `ag-grid`. It's by far in large the most performant table that I've come across and I've insert an absolute metric shit ton of rows into the table without experiencing too much degradation.

Comment: Tnx i think i came across this library, but the supervisor decided to use `vuejs-datatable` for an unknown reason... anyway, the main reason is, I'm loading a huge chunk of data on login. and I have a few reports that use some of this data. so instead of loading the same data a few times in different reports (ands it's a hell of a lot of data), I prefer loading them all to different variables, and then organize only what i need in tables and charts

Comment: which is... a frontend database where i have to set all my data after fetching it from the backend and querying the frontend database for the fast+dynamic experience and without getting any memory crashes?  (I heard of rethinkdb but never understood what it's for and only now it hits me :o)

Comment: how does these frontend libraries load a lot of data to the frontend without cashing anyway? how does  it save them?